# setscheduler() in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

everyone, I found this inside `static int setscheduler(pid_t pid, int policy, struct sched_param *param)` :

```
p->policy = policy;

if (policy != SCHED_OTHER) p->prio = MAX_USER_RT_PRIO-1 - p->rt_priority;
```

p is a pointer to the task descriptor with current pid (parameter above)
so if it's policy is not SCHED_OHTER (it means SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR) but why do we change p->prio such way? what exactly does it mean rt_priority? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**: `rt_priority` means real-time priority and for `SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO` it decides how much time the process will get.

**Long answer**

First of all Linux implements something called `Realtime Process Scheduling` (`SCHED_RR` and `SCHED_FIFO`). Processes operating under these policies always have priority over other processes.
Linux provides 99 realtime priority levels, numbered 1 (lowest) to 99 (highest).

In the kernel, if I recall correctly "smaller numbers mean better preference" - **smaller `p->prio` means better priority**.

**Here us what `sched_setscheduler` looks like:**

```
int sched_setscheduler(pid_t pid, int policy, const struct sched_param *param);
```

**And `sched_param`**

```
struct sched_param {
     int sched_priority;        /* Scheduling priority */
};
```

The integer `sched_priority`, for a policy of `SCHED_RR` or `SCHED_FIFO` means "realtime priority" which I assume is `rt_priority`. So the kernel does the right thing

- Take the maximmum priority
- Subtract the real time priority from that value. The bigger the priority (the more it subtracts) the better treatment by the scheduler.